# Remove values in array equal to subsequent arguments

Tags: javascript

I want this function to work and produce the array [1,1], why doesn't it work?

```
 function destroyer(arr) {
      return arr.reduce(function(a,b){
         if (arguments.slice(1).every(function(arg){
             return arg !== b;
         })) a.push(b);
         return a;
      }, []);
    }

destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3);
```

Comment: What does it produce instead, and why do you think it *should* return `[1,1]`?

Comment: function destroyer(arr) {var args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); // Save arguments in a closure
      return arr.reduce(function(a,b){
         if (args.every(function(arg){ // Access them here
             return arg !== b;
         })) a.push(b);
         return a;
      }, []);
    }


Thanks to Jan for clearing things up as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest

```js
function destroyer(arr) {
  return [].slice.call(arguments, 1).reduce(function(arr, num) {
    return arr.filter(function(item) {
      return num !== item;
    });
  }, arr);
}
```

Or, in ES6,

```js
function destroyer(arr, ...unwanted) {
  return unwanted.reduce((arr,num) => arr.filter(item => num !== item), arr);
}
```

Comment: This is of course much nicer, but it doesn't answer OP's question "why doesn't it work?"

Comment: To note, using `slice` on arguments will prevent the V8 engine from optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/pLp9pgje/)***

`arguments` is not an array. It is "array-like". You need to call the array prototype. Also, splice modifies the array each time it is called, so it should only be used once.

```
function destroyer(arr) {
  //access the array prototype,
  //splice first element off of argument array,
  //and store result
  var args = [].splice.call(arguments,1);
  return arr.reduce(function(p,c){
   //indexOf is an easy way to look for existence in an array
   if( args.indexOf(c) == -1 ) p.push(c);
   return p;
  }, []);
}
```

Calling this on your input, `destroyer([1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3], 2, 3)` will result in `[1,1]`.

Comment: Gotcha, was not aware that arguments is not technically an array.